# How to Query in Ascending using Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Currently even if I do orderByAscending it never does it by ascending.
What is the issue that I do not see? I am using Parse

```
PFQuery *foodList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Food"];

[foodList whereKey:@"date" greaterThanOrEqualTo:minimumDate];
[foodList whereKey:@"date" lessThan:maximumDate];
[foodList orderByAscending:@"expiration_date"];


[foodList findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {

  }];
```

**Example**

```
food_name     expiration_date
Apple           1/2/15
Banana          1/2/15
Pear            1/3/15
Kiwi            1/1/15
```

**Output**

The outputs would be very random.
I am assuming that the list is not being sorted while it is querying. I am unsure how to solve this problem though.

Comment: Can you output the result which you see?

Comment: @AndriyGordiychuk The output is in random order.

Comment: Does the code you put here work?  I think your orderByAscending syntax is missing the @ in front of the string.  It should be [foodList orderByAscending:@"expiration_date"];

Comment: Yes you are correct. I accidentally copy and pasted wrong.

Comment: Check if the date is actually a string instead of a date

Comment: @Carlos yes it is a date.

Comment: Is it possible to post more of the code here.  Is this query by any chance wrapped in a loop?  I'd like to see how it is being called, and what is in the return block.

Comment: @Rufus yes I can, no it isn't in a loop. i'll do that once I get home.

Comment: I know that a Parse query with location constraints can't be sorted. Perhaps this is the same with dates. That being the case, it looks like setting your constraints, then sorting locally, as in Gavin's answer, is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `NSSortDescriptor` variant to do sorting with the Parse SDK and haven't had any issues with that (also filtering on multiple keys like you have is just fine).

This is how you would sort using a descriptor as opposed to a key:

```
PFQuery *foodList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Food"];

[foodList whereKey:@"date" greaterThanOrEqualTo:minimumDate];
[foodList whereKey:@"date" lessThan:maximumDate];

NSSortDescriptor *orderBy = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"expiration_date" ascending:YES];
[foodList orderBySortDescriptor:orderBy];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the Parse Query is fairly unreliable once you start adding in multiple filters, and it may be a bug, but there doesn't seem to be much reason for it.  What I've done, when I have multiple filters, is an NSPredicate.

```
NSPredicate *minPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date >= %@", minimumDate];
NSPredicate *maxPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date < %@", maximumDate];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[minPredicate,maxPredicate]];
PFQuery *foodList = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Food" predicate:predicate];
[foodList orderByAscending:@"expiration_date"];

[foodList findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Another possibility is that your query is filtering for date, and then you order by "expiration_date" and I'm not sure if there's a disconnect between the two.  Make sure your object nomenclature is what you're wanting.